# Symfony production environment always display request.INFO

Tags: php, symfony

I noticed in the symfony logs in the Production Environment that i am getting the following entries:

```
[2017-09-27 09:54:26] request.INFO: Matched route "newsfeedMessage". {"route":"newsfeedMessage","route_parameters":{"_controller":"CP\\FeedBundle\\Controller\\FeedController::newsfeedMessageAction","_route":"newsfeedMessage"},"request_uri":"https://www.website.local:8443/newsfeedMessage","method":"GET"} []
[2017-09-27 09:54:26] request.INFO: Matched route "blog_feed_item". {"route":"blog_feed_item","route_parameters":{"_controller":"CP\\FeedBundle\\Controller\\FeedController::blogFeedItemAction","_route":"blog_feed_item"},"request_uri":"https://www.website.local:8443/blog-feed-item","method":"GET"} []
...
and so on ...
...
```

> my config.yml is setup like this:

```
monolog:
    channels: [error]
    handlers:
        syslog:
            type: rotating_file
            level: ERROR
            bubble: false
            buffer_size: 1024
            handler: file_log
            max_files: 14
        mute:
            type: "null"
            channels: ['snc_redis', 'doctrine', 'security']
        main:
            type: rotating_file
            action_level: error
            handler: grouped
        grouped:
            type: group
            members: [streamed, deduplicated]
        streamed:
            type: rotating_file
            action_level: error
            bubble: false
            buffer_size: 1024
            max_files: 10
        deduplicated:
            type: deduplication
            handler: swift
        swift:
            type: swift_mailer
            from_email: "%mandrill.settings.from_email%"
            to_email: "%monolog_emails%"
            subject: "Website - An error have occurred!"
            level: error
            formatter: monolog.formatter.html
            content_type: text/html
```

> my config_prod.yml looks like this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
```

So i expect that this info are not registered in the logs file.

What is happening and how can I avoid this being added to the logs?

Comment: in `web/app.php`, do your AppKernel is instanciate with second parameter as `true` ? It shouldn't in prod environment

Comment: if i am setting that to true i will get all the logs. so of course that is set to false.

Comment: And you only have Symfony's logs appearing, not your loggers ?

Comment: do you have a config_dev.yml and a config_prod.yml? can you post those?